# How to copy only rows with data from one worksheet to another in a different workbook?

Tags: excel, copy, row, vba

I can pull together a decent macro that does what I need but I forgot that the range will change everyday.
To be specific the row count will get higher. 
  Right now my macro goes through and hides any row that doesn't have today's date and then copies a set range to a worksheet in a different workbook. 
The only problem I have is that range will change everyday, so I figure I need a way to copy only rows with data in them once the rest are hidden and then paste them to the other workbook.

```
Sub automate()
Dim cell As Range
For Each cell In Range("AB2:AB30000")
If cell.Value < Date And cell.Value <> Empty Then cell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
Next
   Range("K28336:K28388,O28336:O28388,P28336:P28388,Q28336:Q28388,R28336:R28388,S28336:S28388,T28336:T28388,U28336:U28388,V28336:V28388,Y28336:Y28388,AA28336:AA28388,AB28336:AB28388").Select
Selection.Copy
Workbooks.Open ("\\gvwac09\Public\Parts\Test\2014 IPU.xlsx")
Sheets("Historical Data").Activate
ActiveSheet.Range("c1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

This is my macro so far. I'm sorry if I didn't format this post correctly, new to this.

Comment: I can see that you are new. I also probably cannot answer your question. Just some general things: Add the language (VBA probably) as a tag. Say clearly what your question is? What doesn't work? What is the current output? What do you expected to see? And use proper English with capitalization. Then the chances for answering your questions will be much higher.

Comment: I am trying to get the formatting to change. I corrected the grammar. I do apologize just been rough trying to get this to go. I tried getting the spaces to do line breaks but I guess I need to read more on how to put things in the post correctly. Thank you for the advice.

Answer (score 1):

I do not understand exacting what you are attempting but I believe I can give you some useful pointers.

I do not explain the statements I use in the code below.  Look them up in the Visual Basic Editor's Help or try searching the web for "Excel VBA xxxxx".  Come back with questions if necessary but the more you can discover for yourself, the quicker your skills will develop.

Firstly you need to find the last row containing data.  Examining every row down to AB30000 just wastes time.  Macro `Demo1` below demonstrates two techniques.  There are more techniques for finding the last row, none of which are appropriate in every situation.  Search StackOverflow for "[excel-vba] find last row".  There are lots of relevant questions and answers although the first technique I use is far and away the most popular.

General advice: If you can break your requirement down to a sequence of single issues (such as "find last row"), you will find it easier to search StackOverflow for an answer.

Always include `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` at the start of your macros if you are going to amend a worksheet.  Without this statement, everytime you hide a row, Excel repaints the screen.

I have created some test data which I hope is representative of your data. I have two worksheets `Source` and `Dest`.  `Source` contains the full set of data.  I copy the selected rows to `Dest`.

I have used Auto Filter which will be much faster than your technique if it will give you the effect you seek.  Play with Auto Filter from the keyboard.  If you can get the effect you seek, turn on the Macro Recorder, use Auto Filter to get the selection you seek and switch the Macro Recorder off.  Adjust the Macro Recorder's statements to remove `Selection` and replace the corresponding statements in `Demo2`.

The secret of `Demo2` is `Set Rng = .AutoFilter.Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` which sets `Rng` to the visible rows.  If you cannot get Auto Filter to work as you wish and you decide to use your current technique to set uninteresting rows invisible, keep this statement to get the remaining rows.  However, I think macro `Demo3` uses a better technique.

```
Option Explicit
Sub demo1()

  Dim ColLast As Long
  Dim Rng As Range
  Dim RowLast As Long

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  With Worksheets("Source")

    ' This searches up from the bottom of column AB for a cell with a value.
    ' It is the VBA equivalent of placing the cursor at the bottom of column AB
    ' and clicking Ctrl+Up.
    RowLast = .Cells(Rows.Count, "AB").End(xlUp).Row
    Debug.Print "Last row with value in column AB: " & RowLast

    ' This searches for the last cell with a value.
    Set Rng = .Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=.Range("A1"), SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)

    If Rng Is Nothing Then
      ' Worksheet is empty
    Else
      RowLast = Rng.Row
      ColLast = Rng.Column
      Debug.Print "Last cell with value is: (" & RowLast & ", " & ColLast & _
                  ") = " & Replace(Rng.Address, "$", "")
    End If

  End With

End Sub
Sub Demo2()

  Dim Rng As Range
  Dim SearchDate As String

  SearchDate = "14-May-14"

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  With Sheets("Source")
    .Cells.AutoFilter
    .Cells.AutoFilter Field:=28, Criteria1:=SearchDate
    Set Rng = .AutoFilter.Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
  End With

  ' Rng.Address has a maximum length of a little under 256 characters.
  ' Rng holds the addresses of all the visible rows but you cannot display
  ' all those addresses in an easy manner.  However, this is only to give
  ' you an idea of what is in Rng; the Copy statement below uses the full
  ' set of addresses.
  Debug.Print "Visible rows: " & Rng.Address

  Rng.Copy Worksheets("Dest").Range("A1")

End Sub
Sub Demo3()

  Dim RngToBeCopied As Range
  Dim RowCrnt As Long
  Dim RowLast As Long
  Dim SearchDate As Long

  ' Excel holds dates as integers and times as fractions.
  SearchDate = CLng(DateValue("20 May 2014"))

  With Worksheets("Source")

    RowLast = .Cells(Rows.Count, "AB").End(xlUp).Row

    ' Include header row in range to be copied
    Set RngToBeCopied = .Rows(1)

    For RowCrnt = 2 To RowLast
      If .Cells(RowCrnt, "AB").Value = SearchDate Then
        Set RngToBeCopied = Union(RngToBeCopied, .Rows(RowCrnt))
      End If
    Next

  End With

  Debug.Print RngToBeCopied.Address
  RngToBeCopied.Copy Worksheets("Dest").Range("A1")

End Sub
```